# Как связать мобильное приложение с WP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile-web

При помощи одного из сервисов прототипирования собрал "основу" для приложения, теперь нужно связать его с сайтом на wp... Как лучше и проще всего подойти к этому вопросу?

В целом, что такое api - понимание есть, только их там несколько, какой выбрать если мне нужна авторизация в приложении, а также чтение/изменение данных? Я так понял, что мне нужен rest api?

Если да, то прошу поделиться ссылкой на понятный мануал, если нет, то в направьте в нужном направлении...

Спасибо!

Comment: Расшифруй "связать". Какие задачи?

Comment: мне нужна авторизация в приложении, а также чтение/изменение данных

Comment: О, блин сорри. Это ж  есть в вопросе, а я тогда это почему-то пропустил...  Да, рест-апи.

Answer (score 1):

> Я так понял, что мне нужен rest api?
>
> Если да, то прошу поделиться ссылкой на понятный мануал, если нет, то
> в направьте в нужном направлении..

Да, REST-API.
Начни отсюда https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/